# rails forms submit confirmation message without jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use rails5 forms to create a simple form where the user signs up for newsletter. I got stuck with the last step. After the user click submit message, then then there should be a message confirming reception of the email.
For now, I found that I can do

```
<%= button.tag 'Submit', data: { confirm: 'We received your email', class: 'b-button'} %>
```

This gives me an alert (pop up) message, which is not ideal. Ideally, I would like to have a message above the button pop up or I would like the whole form to have a fadeout effect. I do not want to use any vanilla js or jquery, is there a way to do this in pure rails?

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the `data:` from this line.
- In the controller which is handling this form, you can add these lines

```
if whatever.save
   flash[:notice] = "This is my message"
   redirect_to wherever
```

What is happening is that upon successful saving, you will have a nice flash message on screen, you would have to add an `else` statement and re-render the form again upon failure of submission.